# Problem with table latex

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I have a small problem with my thesis. It's the first time I work with latex and I have a problem with tables. I create the table below

```
\begin{table}[H]
%\centering
\caption{Mobile apps categories with some exemplary apps}
\label{table:1} %% \ref{table:1} pour la ref
\begin{tabular}{||c l l c l l||}
%%\hline
\hlineB{3.5}
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Examples of apps} & \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Category} & 
\textbf{Examples of apps} \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\hline
1 & Calendar & Calendar & 13 & Weather & Weather \\  \hline
2 & Communication & Messenger, WhatsApp, TrueCaller & 14 & Games & Texas Poker, Quick ball, Ludo King 
\\ \hline
3 & Video Players and Editors & YouTube, HUAWEI Video & 15 & Music and Audio & Musique, Shazam, 
 spotify \\ \hline
4 & Clock & Clock, Horloge, Alarme & 16 & Entertainment & Netflix \\  \hline
5 & Sytem Tool & Setting, Calculatrice & 17 & Education & Google Translate  \\ \hline
6 & Health and fitness & Health, SmokeCount & 18 & Personnalisation & Theme, Wallpapers \\ \hline
7 & Phone and SMS  & Contacts, Dialler, Messages & 19 & Sports & beIN sport, Live Football Scores\\ 
\hline
 8 & Social Media & Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn & 20 & News and Magazines & Google Podcast, Opera 
 News\\ \hline
 9 & Photography & Camera, Gallery & 21 & Shopping & IKEA\\ \hline
 10 & Lifestyle & Tinder, Jumia & 22 & Finance &  STB, CIC, Boursorama Banque\\ \hline
 11 & Maps and Navigation & Google Maps, Bolt & 23 & Productivity & PDF reader, Notepad, Docs\\ \ \ v 
\hline
 12 & Travel and Local & Kayak, Booking.com &    &    &   \\%%[1ex]
 \hlineB{3.5}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

[image]
Thank you so so much for you help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That the table is wider than the page and is thus cut off? If so, you may want to a take a look at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that the table is wider than the page, how can I do?

Comment: The answer to [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) contains a lot of useful approaches should be applicable to your table, as well. If you want a more specific advice regarding our table, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the document class as well as the relevant packages. If you use the `geometry` package, also include the corresponding settings.

Comment: Any news? You got two answers. Please inform us, if they solve your problem and please accept this one(by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer) which solution on the best way fulfill your expectations.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Recently I discover the `tabularray` package ... For exercise let mi show two possible solution using this so versatile package for table settings. The first show table on landscape oriented page, the second one show redesigned table which can be easily fit on portrait page. The both use standard font size 10pt, however if is desired the second one can use also 11pt or 12pt and can be fit on page also when the package `geometry` is removed:

Since you not provide any information about your document design, I use `\usepackage[vmargin=30mm]{geometry}` for determining page layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % landscape
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, 
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Mobile apps categories with some exemplary apps}
\label{table:1} %% \ref{table:1} pour la ref
    \begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
                 colspec={c ll c ll},
                 row{odd}={gray!30}
                 }
    \hline
\textbf{No.}    
    &   \textbf{Category}         
        &   \textbf{Examples of apps}       
            &   \textbf{No.} 
                &   \textbf{Category}  
                    &   \textbf{Examples of apps}           \\
    \hline
1   & Calendar        & Calendar  
    & 13 & Weather  & Weather   \\
2   & Communication & Messenger, WhatsApp, TrueCaller   
    & 14 & Games    & Texas Poker, Quick ball, Ludo King    \\
3   & Video Players and Editors & YouTube, HUAWEI Video           
    & 15 & Music and Audio      & Musique, Shazam, spotify  \\
4   & Clock         & Clock, Horloge, Alarme          
    & 16 & Entertainment        & Netflix                   \\
5   & Sytem Tool    & Setting, Calculatrice           
    & 17 & Education            & Google Translate          \\ 
6   & Health and fitness        & Health, SmokeCount              
    & 18 & Personnalisation     & Theme, Wallpapers         \\
7   & Phone and SMS & Contacts, Dialler, Messages     
    & 19 & Sports   & beIN sport, Live Football Scores      \\
8   & Social Media  & Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn   
    & 20 & News and Magazines   & Google Podcast, Opera News\\
9   & Photography   & Camera, Gallery                 
    & 21 & Shopping & IKEA                                  \\
10  & Lifestyle     & Tinder, Jumia                   
    & 22 & Finance  & STB, CIC, Boursorama Banque           \\ 
11  & Maps and Navigation       & Google Maps, Bolt               
    & 23 & Productivity         & PDF reader, Notepad, Docs \\
12  & Travel and Local          & Kayak, Booking.com              
    &    &  &                                               \\
    \hline 
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

    \begin{table}
\caption{Mobile apps categories with some exemplary apps}
\label{table:1} %% \ref{table:1} pour la ref
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={c X[l]X[l]},
                 row{odd}={gray!30}
                 }
    \hline
\textbf{No.}
    &   \textbf{Category}   &   \textbf{Examples of apps}   \\
    \hline
1   & Calendar          & Calendar                          \\
2   & Communication     & Messenger, WhatsApp, TrueCaller   \\
3   & Video Players and Editors 
                        & YouTube, HUAWEI Video             \\
4   & Clock             & Clock, Horloge, Alarme            \\
5   & Sytem Tool        & Setting, Calculatrice             \\
6   & Health and fitness    & Health, SmokeCount            \\
7   & Phone and SMS     & Contacts, Dialler, Messages       \\
8   & Social Media      & Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn     \\
9   & Photography       & Camera, Gallery                   \\
10  & Lifestyle         & Tinder, Jumia                     \\
11  & Maps and Navigation   & Google Maps, Bolt             \\
12  & Travel and Local      & Kayak, Booking.com            \\
13 & Weather            & Weather                           \\
14 & Games              & Texas Poker, Quick ball, Ludo King\\
15 & Music and Audio    & Musique, Shazam, spotify          \\
16 & Entertainment      & Netflix                           \\
17 & Education          & Google Translate                  \\
18 & Personnalisation   & Theme, Wallpapers                 \\
19 & Sports             & beIN sport, Live Football Scores  \\
20 & News and Magazines & Google Podcast, Opera News        \\
21 & Shopping           & IKEA                              \\
22 & Finance            & STB, CIC, Boursorama Banque       \\
23 & Productivity       & PDF reader, Notepad, Docs         \\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

On landscape page:

[image]

On portrait page, redesigned (only three columns and twice as many lines, it still can be fit on the one page):

[image]

Comment: Two remarks: (1) `tblr` environment doesn't use `\tabcolsep`, but you can use `colsep=3pt` in the preamble of the environment; (2) `rowspec={*{7}{Q[gray!30]Q}}` may be replaced with more meaningful `row{odd}={gray!30}`.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank very much you for comment! I still learning this package (so I mentioned *for exercise*) and stil somewhere use approach known me  from "classic" table environments. I will correct answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

By having the table in landscape mode it will fit in the page and it will be easy to read.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape} % landscape

\usepackage{hhline} % double line

\usepackage{array} % strecth celld

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\caption{Mobile apps categories with some exemplary apps}\label{table:1} %% \ref{table:1} pour la ref
\smallskip  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % exaonds the cells vertically
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{%
    ||c l l c l l||}
    \hline
    \textbf{No.}                  & \textbf{Category}         & \textbf{Examples of apps}       & \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Category}  & \textbf{Examples of apps}  \\ [0.5ex]
    \hhline{======}
    1 & Calendar                  & Calendar                        & 13 & Weather            & Weather                            \\ \hline
    2 & Communication             & Messenger, WhatsApp, TrueCaller & 14 & Games              & Texas Poker, Quick ball, Ludo King \\ \hline
    3 & Video Players and Editors & YouTube, HUAWEI Video           & 15 & Music and Audio    & Musique, Shazam, spotify           \\ \hline
    4 & Clock                     & Clock, Horloge, Alarme          & 16 & Entertainment      & Netflix                            \\ \hline
    5 & Sytem Tool                & Setting, Calculatrice           & 17 & Education          & Google Translate                   \\ \hline
    6 & Health and fitness        & Health, SmokeCount              & 18 & Personnalisation   & Theme, Wallpapers                  \\ \hline
    7 & Phone and SMS             & Contacts, Dialler, Messages     & 19 & Sports             & beIN sport, Live Football Scores   \\ \hline
    8 & Social Media              & Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn   & 20 & News and Magazines & Google Podcast, Opera  News        \\ \hline
    9 & Photography               & Camera, Gallery                 & 21 & Shopping           & IKEA                               \\ \hline
    10& Lifestyle                 & Tinder, Jumia                   & 22 & Finance            & STB, CIC, Boursorama Banque        \\ \hline
    11& Maps and Navigation       & Google Maps, Bolt               & 23 & Productivity       & PDF reader, Notepad, Docs          \\ \hline
    12& Travel and Local          & Kayak, Booking.com              &    &                    &                                    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape} 
    
\end{document}
```

This second example uses the package `nicematrix`, replacing the horizontal lines with rows of alternate colors.

[image: n]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape} % landscape

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\caption{Mobile apps categories with some exemplary apps}\label{table:1} %% \ref{table:1} pour la ref
\smallskip  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{%
    |c l l c l l|}[cell-space-limits = 6pt, code-before=\rowcolor{gray!50}{1} \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}] % alternate row colors and expand cells
    \hline
    \textbf{No.}                  & \textbf{Category}         & \textbf{Examples of apps}       & \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Category}  & \textbf{Examples of apps}  \\[0.5ex]
    1 & Calendar                  & Calendar                        & 13 & Weather            & Weather                            \\ 
    2 & Communication             & Messenger, WhatsApp, TrueCaller & 14 & Games              & Texas Poker, Quick ball, Ludo King \\ 
    3 & Video Players and Editors & YouTube, HUAWEI Video           & 15 & Music and Audio    & Musique, Shazam, spotify           \\ 
    4 & Clock                     & Clock, Horloge, Alarme          & 16 & Entertainment      & Netflix                            \\ 
    5 & Sytem Tool                & Setting, Calculatrice           & 17 & Education          & Google Translate                   \\ 
    6 & Health and fitness        & Health, SmokeCount              & 18 & Personnalisation   & Theme, Wallpapers                  \\ 
    7 & Phone and SMS             & Contacts, Dialler, Messages     & 19 & Sports             & beIN sport, Live Football Scores   \\ 
    8 & Social Media              & Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn   & 20 & News and Magazines & Google Podcast, Opera  News        \\ 
    9 & Photography               & Camera, Gallery                 & 21 & Shopping           & IKEA                               \\ 
    10& Lifestyle                 & Tinder, Jumia                   & 22 & Finance            & STB, CIC, Boursorama Banque        \\ 
    11& Maps and Navigation       & Google Maps, Bolt               & 23 & Productivity       & PDF reader, Notepad, Docs          \\ 
    12& Travel and Local          & Kayak, Booking.com              &    &                    &                                    \\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape} 
    
\end{document}
```