# How can I make such a Fancy table in Latex?

Tags: tables, formatting

How can I make this style of table in Latex with a specific colour gradient in borders, for example from dark blue to light blue, the First horizontal two borders should look like that :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Can you show this? Recoding your table from scratch is not fun!

Comment: Alternating row colors in a table can be achieved using the `\rowcolors` command which is accessible when adding `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to the preamble of a document.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598976/problem-with-table-latex/599321#599321

Comment: Is there any way that I can change the colour of borders, I mean with colour degradation ?

Comment: @TTT: What kind of borders are you referring to? In the screenshot you added to your question there are no colored borders, but just a colored background. Also, what does "colour degradation" refer to? Do you mean a colour gradient?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if there is a way to change the colour of borders from simple black to something like colour degradation (for example from dark blue to light blue)

Comment: @TTT You can define your own color by using `xcolor.sty` and the tag is `\definecolor{colorone}{cmyk}{0.5,0.25,0,0.1}`

Comment: Ok I will try this Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Just a proof-of-concept, with the help of `nicematrix` package.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for \tabularnote
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5pt} % just for test

\begin{NiceTabular}[hlines]{cccc}
  2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
  3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 3 & 1 & 0%
  \tabularnote{default color}
\end{NiceTabular}%
\space
\begin{NiceTabular}[hlines, rules/color=white]{cccc}
  2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
  3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 3 & 1 & 0%
  \tabularnote{axis-shading color}
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}} {
      \fill[left color=blue!50!black, right color=blue!50] 
        ([shift={(-.5\tabcolsep, -.5\arrayrulewidth)}] \i-|1) rectangle
        ([shift={(.5\tabcolsep, .5\arrayrulewidth)}] \i-|last);
    };
  }
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original answer**

Here is a way combining the color series in `xcolor` package and the `\arrayrulecolor`, provided by `colortbl` package, to set color of horizontal rule in a tabular.

Check the corresponding package docs for more info.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolorseries{tblrule}{rgb}{last}{blue!50!black}{blue!50}

\begin{document}
\resetcolorseries[5]{tblrule}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  \arrayrulecolor{tblrule!!+}
  \toprule
  a & b \\ \midrule
  a & b \\ \midrule
  a & b \\ \midrule
  a & b \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Please keep the textual question description and the attached image for demonstration, as consistent as possible.

Comment: Thanks you, but you have made it in a vertical way, can you make it horizontal with the gradient of colours of course, Thanks you

Comment: Ah, with your newly added image showing what the "colour gradient" means, I knew my answer hit the wrong target. I'm afraid that traditional table packages cannot do the trick directly, and I will check if `nicematrix` package is capable.

Comment: Hmmm, `nicematrix`'s `\hline` makes use of `\noalign` as well, but not pgf drawing.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's for beamer right ?

Comment: @TTT Answer updated to show a proof-of-concept. And, `nicematrix` is a general package not only for `beamer`.